# Execute a console.log for each time a variable change statement

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to run a console.log every time a variable changes from true to false and vice versa but only once. I don't want the console.log to appear as long as the variable = true or false.
So when variable = true it makes one console.log and when it changes to false it makes another one and that every time the variable changes state. Do you have an idea how to do this?

Comment: can you show code for what you've tried?

Comment: Typically one does this by adding a log in the code that changes the variable...

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I've not tried anything, all I can think about is sending console.log repeatedly and that's not what I want.

Comment: Here's the currently supported way of doing this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/5uxc6Lym/

Comment: Thank you so much @ChrisG !

Answer (score 0):

did you try Object.prototype.watch()??

I think you need a watch method for tracking your variables changes! remember, this way is not supporting IE browsers, but if you want to work with watch methods, I suggest using The Progressive JavaScript Framework like vue, react or angular!!

any way, see more details about watch() methods in :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch

Comment: This is for use with discord.js and Watch is not supported.